# Concatenate output of sed to bash script variable

Tags: bash, sed, echo, concatenation

I have the following:

```
whole_string=""

while read line; do
    line=echo $line | sed 's/hello/bye/g'
    whole_string=$whole_string$line'\n'

done

echo -e $whole_string
```

I am trying to:

1) read each line from `stdin` and change any instance of `hello` to `bye`.

2) append the changed string `line` to `$whole_string`

3) Finally, print `$whole_string`

When I try run this, I get a `command not found` error at this line:

`line=echo $line | sed 's/hello/bye/g'`

Could someone please explain to me how I should write this correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) when you want to assign output of commands to a variable. See [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) for replacing all strings in a variable. e.g. `${line//hello/bye}`.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply

```
readarray -t all
printf '%s\n' "${all[@]//hello/bye}"
```